# Why does providing a partial function to map throw at runtime rather than give a compile error?

Tags: scala, partialfunction

Apologies if this is obvious but I am new to scala and I am getting two unexpected behaviors with the following code:

```
Seq(1, "a", 2, "b") map { 
    case i: Int => i+1
}
```

1) I would have expected to get back a collection where the strings are unchanged and the numbers are incremented by 1 but instead I get an error.

2) I believe the `case i: Int => i + 1` syntax represents a partial function which is defined for Ints. But it seems map  takes a total function, so why does this even compile? Wouldn't it be better for the compiler to help me out? It is always better to move runtime exceptions to compile time exceptions.

Comment: Since you said you are new to the language, I hope an advice will come handy. Since **Scala** has a strong and static type system, usually one would like to relay in the compiler to catch most of simple bugs and typos, in order to do that, types like `Any` or `List[Any]` should be avoided as they will allow a lot of bugs.

Comment: thank you @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez for the good advice! i'm sorry i cannot up-vote your comment, i do not have permission.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`map()` does not take a partial function as the passed parameter, but `collect()` does.

```
Seq(1, "a", 2, "b") collect {
  case i: Int => i+1
}
//res0: Seq[Int] = List(2, 3)
```

Notice how input that is not defined for the partial function is not passed through but is simply dropped. What you don't want dropped needs a handler, even if it's just a `case _ =>` default handler.

```
Seq(1, "a", 2, "b", 'z') collect {
  case i: Int    => i+1        //increment ints
  case c: Char   => c.toUpper  //capitalize chars
  case s: String => s          //strings pass through
}
//res0: Seq[Any] = List(2, a, 3, b, Z)
```

When you pass a partial function to `map()` the compiler does not complain because `trait PartialFunction[-A, +B] extends (A) => B`. In other words, a partial function **is** a type of function.

It's also worth noting that, when dealing with partial functions...

> It is the responsibility of the caller to call `isDefinedAt` before calling `apply`...

So we can conclude that `collect()` does that and `map()` doesn't.

Comment: ooooh ok cool, so THIS makes sense now, it is a subtype so it passes but then it throws because the `map` implementation doesn't check `isDeifnedAt`? Could I ask why not? is it just a part of how the standard collections are defined, do you know why? I really like your `collect` idea but then it will skip those inputs which is  useful in other cases but in my cases i want them unchanged. If you add the `map` example from Mario's answer i will accept yours as the most complete. Also if you can answer my questions about why `map` doesn't check. thank you so much.

Comment: @StanL `map` doesn't check `isDefinedAt` because `isDefinedAt` is only defined for partial functions. Since `map` takes a regular function (and accepts partial functions only because they're a subtype of regular functions), it actually can't call `isDefinedAt`. `map` is only meant to be used with function that are defined for all values in the list. I think what you really want to ask is *why* partial functions are a subtype of regular functions and the reason for that is that it'd be inconvenient if you couldn't use the `{case ... => ...}` syntax with `map` etc.

Comment: @StanL Note that `{case ... => ...}` always has the type `PartialFunction` regardless of whether the pattern matching is actually partial or not. So if higher-order functions like `map` wouldn't accept partial functions in lieu of regular functions, you'd never be able to use the `{case ... => ...}` syntax with them even if the match were exhaustive.

Comment: @StanL Also note that `PartialFunction` not being a subtype of regular functions wouldn't really solve your question either. It would disallow `map {case ... => ...}`, but it would still allow `map {x => x match { case ... => ...}}` (since that actually has the type `A => B` instead of `PartialFunction[A,B]`), which would still throw the exact same pattern matching error. So really the issue is with your pattern match not being exhaustive rather than with the fact that the `{case...}`-syntax happens to produce a `PartialFunction`.

Comment: very interesting, all of that makes sense, i will mark your answer as accepted because it is the most complete one, perhaps if more people upvote on my question i can get enough rep haha :)

Comment: because i am new to the site, it says that my upvote is recorded but not made public... so i'm not sure if you can see the upvote.

Comment: I think this is different, "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." :(

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
Seq(1, "a", 2, "b") map {
  case i: Int => i + 1
  case any => any
}
```

which outputs

```
res0: Seq[Any] = List(2, a, 3, b)
```

The reason `Seq(1, "a", 2, "b") map { case i: Int => i + 1 }` compiles is because type of `Seq(1, "a", 2, "b")` is `Seq[Any]`. On the other hand, the following

```
Seq("a", "b").map { case i: Int => i + 1 }
```

gives compiler error

```
scrutinee is incompatible with pattern type;
[error]  found   : Int
[error]  required: String
[error]   Seq("a", "b").map { case i: Int => i + 1 }
```

because `Seq("a", "b")` has type `Seq[String]` whilst `{ case i: Int => i + 1 }` has type `PartialFunction[Int, Int]`.

Comment: thank you for the answer. hmm so what type should i make the Seq be in order to get a compile time error that i'm passing a partial function when it needs a total function? i assume that is the reason i'm getting the runtime error? i'm sorry your answer confuses me a bit but i do see that it works.  i assume because i don't provide any type for `any` it is assumed to be `: Any`?

Comment: Mario, i accepted the other answer but i'm also upvoting your answer because it is very good (i'm sorry i cannot accept both). however, because i am new to the site, it says that my upvote is recorded but not made public... so i'm not sure if you can see the upvote.